# Convert Func<T1, T2, ..., TResult> to Func<object[], object>

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, func

The short question:

Is it possible to convert various Func<T1, T2, ..., TResult> delegates into a common Func<object[], object> signature where the arguments are combined into a parameter array. And then still be able to invoke the methods directly without reflection/dynamics?

Something along these kind of lines:

```
public static void Register<T, TArg1, TArg2>(Expression<Func<TArg1, TArg2, T>> action)
{
    // Convert the function using some Expression methods... 
    Expression<Func<object[], object>> exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<object[], object>>(action.Body, action.Parameters);
    
    // Compile the code ready to invoke whenever it is needed...
}
```

Background:

I'm trying to build an P2P game library for sending and receiving/actioning RPCs. RPC methods are registered with a controller class. And when a matching RPC is received the method should be invoked with the arguments.

I would like to avoid reflection ideally, as the methods will all be strongly typed as they are registered, so it seems that generics, lambdas and expressions should be able to achieve my goals.

My best attempt so far involves wrapping the methods in a class which records the types, but I'm not happy with it because it requires creating an argument object instead of using the usual comma separated params:

```
public abstract class GameActionBase
{
    public Func<object, object> Action { get; protected set; }
    public Type ArgsType { get; protected set; }
    public Type ReturnType { get; protected set; }
}

public class GameAction<TArgs, TReturn> : GameActionBase
{
    public GameAction(Func<TArgs, TReturn> gameAction)
    {
        ArgsType = typeof(TArgs);
        ReturnType = typeof(TReturn);
        Action = args => gameAction((TArgs)args);
    }
}

public static class GameActions
{
    private static Dictionary<string, GameActionBase> registered;

    static GameActions()
    {
        registered = new Dictionary<string, GameActionBase>();
        SubscribeActionEvents();
    }

    public static void Register(string actionName, GameActionBase actionInfo)
    {
        registered.Add(actionName, actionInfo);
    }

    public static void Unregister(string actionName)
    {
        registered.Remove(actionName);
    }

    private static void SubscribeActionEvents()
    {
        Events.ActionReceivedEvent += (sender, action) =>
        {
            ProcessActionReceived(action);
        };
    }

    private static void ProcessActionReceived(ActionEventArgs action)
    {
        GameActionBase info;
        if (registered.TryGetValue(action.Name, out info))
        {
            object args = JsonUtility.FromJson(action.Args, info.ArgsType);
            object res = info.Action(args);
            // etc...
        }
    }
}
```

Example RPC method:

```
public class TestActionClass
{
    public TestActionReceivedState TestActionReceived(TestActionReceivedArgs args)
    {   
        // Process game action

        // Return result
        return new TestActionReceivedState
        {
            state1 = args.firstArg,
            state2 = args.secondArg
        };        
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class TestActionReceivedState
{
    public string state1;
    public string state2;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class TestActionReceivedArgs
{
    public string firstArg;
    public string secondArg;
    public string thirdArg;
    public string fourthArg;
    public string fifthArg;
}
```

Registering the method:

```
TestActionClass testClass = new TestActionClass();
var testAction = new GameAction<TestActionReceivedArgs, TestActionReceivedState>(testClass.TestActionReceived);

GameActions.Register("TestActionReceived", testAction);
```

To simplify the API and allow any combination of params for GameAction methods, I would like to create generic Register methods which take expressions and transform them into a common signature which can be stored in a collection and then be directly invoked without reflection/dynamic invocation. Is this possible? If so, how is this achieved?

Comment: Allocating arrays on something as low level as networking is a sure recipe for bad performance at such a level that you can't work around without a complete rewrite.

Comment: @Blindy Would you care to expand on your point? Why is allocating on an array going to cause such bad performance here? I don't think I've ever had a performance issue caused by using an array.

Comment: Then you haven't read anything technical. The entire reason .Net Framework has been killed is because it was impossible to get rid of allocations at its lowest levels, and it has been rewritten to use `Span<>` and value types as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I'm not looking to reinvent .NET. These game action RPCs may be received only around 30 times a second or so, so I don't expect array allocation is going to be the bottleneck here.

Comment: Allocating an array and boxing / unboxing every value argument would add a lot of overhead. Since you could generate an expression to pass the argument values from an array through to the method, why not call your incoming message parser inside that expression, avoiding the need to allocate anything extra. While still conforming to the same method signature.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman That sounds like a useful approach. Although I'm struggling to visualise the code structure. Do you mean that the subscription to the game action event occurs inside the expression, and would this mean there will be no need for a collection of expressions/functions?

Comment: Start by writing one example by hand (eg https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwHQBkCWAdgI7YCiAHgA4BOApgM4P4D2hDA3MslAMyYx0ABQCGNBnRroA3snTzM/IgBd0AcTrKAkoWUAKAJToAvAD50cLkgWL0K9ZtxsA5oZPnLchX0xwAbJgALL4wALKaABYswHr2+AA0drroAFYG0gC+XvI+WAFQwaFustY2CpS0jMxsADxYMDWi4pKm5nQUIgC2VAA2dCbo/WYh4cpRMXTYGtq6homT006ErgYGVjZZSBlAA==) then work out how to build the expression tree.... And finally compile the expression.

Comment: I'd like to help but there are so many questions: You're using JSON anyway, why not do `Func<string, object>` instead and let the method(s) parse the JSON? Why is it `Expression<Func<...>>` instead of just `Func<...>`? Why does every method have to return `object`? Do you type check and cast the return value later (probably wrong overall approach then) or does it return JSON/something similar?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman thanks, I'll look at your example in a but detail later.

Comment: @Scmid I'm using JSON (at least for now, for simplicity) to pass the RPC message across the network, but the methods shouldn't know about this implementation detail. I intend the library to handle all parsing of the messages and let the methods deal directly with their own params.

Comment: My example used an Expression wrapped Func because I think I will need metadata about the methods in order to transform them. My current working example at the bottom works without an Expression but requires the method args to be a single object, which I'm trying to avoid, if possible

Comment: Every RPC method returns an object which contains the mutated state as a result of the method action. This is an early stage investigation in a possible distributed consensus mechanism in a p2p multiplayer library.

Comment: The return value is serialised then hashed/whatever as part of the consensus system.

Comment: When an RPC message is received over the network, I want to parse the message in the library, match it to a method in my registered methods collection and invoke it with the arguments list in the parsed RPC message

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Looking at your code again and investigating further, it sounds like your approach is similar to that used by ASP.NET with their parameter binding. Described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73426685/how-is-delegate-being-cast-to-requestdelegate-in-asp-net-core. They use a RequestDelegateFactory to generate code which passes arbitrary params to mapped delegates.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is rewrite `Func<Foo, Bar, Baz`> as a function which takes one tuple argument instead, `Func<(Foo, Bar), Baz>`. They are more or less equivalent and tuples are fast. Tuple is implemented like this internally:

```
public struct ValueTuple<T1> { public T1 Item1; ... }
public struct ValueTuple<T1, T2> { ... }
public struct ValueTuple<T1, T2, T3> { ... }
// stops at 8 elements
```

(See [Source.Dot.Net](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ValueTuple.cs,111be3ce2ab34378) for examples)

Using ValueTuple as an inspiration, we can solve your question. You'll have to write a bunch of overloads but it's not too bad. I used `Action<>` (essentially `Func<void>`) instead of `Func<>` or `Expression<Func<>>` to keep the solution smaller but it should be trivial to retrofit them. Keep in mind that `Expression`s don't support everything, which might severely limit your code (for example, `() => {}` is not allowed because block bodies are not supported). I also removed `object` because generics are safer, a lot faster, give better error messages and work just as well here.

`Register` takes variants of `Action<T1, T2, ...>` and wraps them in a `Action<(T1, T2, ...)>`. We save the `Action<(...)>` and `typeof((T1, T2,...))` in a `Dictionary<string, (Type, Delegate)>`. `Delegate` because it's the common parent class.

`ProcessAction` does the same thing. Takes overloads of `T1, T2, ...` and converts them into `(T1, T2, ...)`, then calls the stored action.

```
public class Dispatcher
{
    public enum ProcessResult
    {
        Success,
        NotRegistered,
        ArgumentTypesNotSuppored,
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<string, (Type, Delegate)> registered = new();

    public void Register<T>(string name, Action<T> action)
    {
        registered.Add(name, (typeof(T), action));
    }
    public void Register<T0, T1>(string name, Action<T0, T1> action)
    {
        registered.Add(name, (typeof((T0, T1)), ((T0 a, T1 b) v) => action(v.a, v.b)));
    }
    public void Register<T0, T1, T2>(string name, Action<T0, T1, T2> action)
    {
        registered.Add(name, (typeof((T0, T1, T2)), ((T0 a, T1 b, T2 c) v) => action(v.a, v.b, v.c)));
    }

    public void Unregister(string name)
    {
        registered.Remove(name);
    }


    public ProcessResult ProcessAction<T>(string name, T args)
    {
        if (registered.TryGetValue(name, out var typeAndAction))
        {
            var (type, action) = typeAndAction;

            if (typeof(T) != type)
            {
                // throw in debug because this is a nightmare to figure out if you're still developing. 
                // Don't throw in release because you don't want your game to crash.
#if DEBUG
                throw new NotSupportedException($"Type mismatch: {name} expects argument type {type} but was supplied with {typeof(T)}");
#else
                return ProcessResult.ArgumentTypesNotSuppored;
#endif
            }

            ((Action<T>)action)(args);
            return ProcessResult.Success;
        }

        return ProcessResult.NotRegistered;
    }

    public ProcessResult ProcessAction<T0, T1>(string name, T0 args0, T1 args1) => ProcessAction<(T0, T1)>(name, (args0, args1));
    public ProcessResult ProcessAction<T0, T1, T2>(string name, T0 args0, T1 args1, T2 args2) => ProcessAction<(T0, T1, T2)>(name, (args0, args1, args2));

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really like this approach. It's looks like it will take me most of the way to where I want to be.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only 8 `Func` delegates defined by the framework, it's quite easy to make what you want with extension methods:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static Func<object[], object> ToObjects<T1, R>(this Func<T1, R> func) => (object[] os) => (R)func((T1)os[0]);
    public static Func<object[], object> ToObjects<T1, T2, R>(this Func<T1, T2, R> func) => (object[] os) => (R)func((T1)os[0], (T2)os[1]);
    public static Func<object[], object> ToObjects<T1, T2, T3, R>(this Func<T1, T2, T3, R> func) => (object[] os) => (R)func((T1)os[0], (T2)os[1], (T3)os[2]);
    public static Func<object[], object> ToObjects<T1, T2, T3, T4, R>(this Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, R> func) => (object[] os) => (R)func((T1)os[0], (T2)os[1], (T3)os[2], (T4)os[3]);
    public static Func<object[], object> ToObjects<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, R>(this Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, R> func) => (object[] os) => (R)func((T1)os[0], (T2)os[1], (T3)os[2], (T4)os[3], (T5)os[4]);
    public static Func<object[], object> ToObjects<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, R>(this Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, R> func) => (object[] os) => (R)func((T1)os[0], (T2)os[1], (T3)os[2], (T4)os[3], (T5)os[4], (T6)os[5]);
    public static Func<object[], object> ToObjects<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, R>(this Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, R> func) => (object[] os) => (R)func((T1)os[0], (T2)os[1], (T3)os[2], (T4)os[3], (T5)os[4], (T6)os[5], (T7)os[6]);
    public static Func<object[], object> ToObjects<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, R>(this Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, R> func) => (object[] os) => (R)func((T1)os[0], (T2)os[1], (T3)os[2], (T4)os[3], (T5)os[4], (T6)os[5], (T7)os[6], (T8)os[7]);
}
```

Now it's easy to run:

```
Func<int, string, string> f = (n, t) =>
    String.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(1, n).Select(x => t));

Func<object[], object> g = f.ToObjects();

Console.WriteLine(g(new object[] { 5, "Hello" }));
```

That produces:

> Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello

Comment: Thanks for this, this answers my question directly and is very simple. I'm just considering whether the Tuple method that @CookedCthulhu is going to be a better fit for my use case.